# Add Row in YUI table

Tags: javascript, yui

When I type any data in textbox and as soon as user clicks on add button, the entered value of text box will add as a row in yui table. yui use datasource and then append rows, but in my case I have no data.

Comment: ... right ... You should post some code, because else we can guess as much as we want. Anywayz; if you want to add data, you can use the datasource like an array feeding arrays. in other words you can use the datasource.push(data) function to add items to the datatable. Do not reload the page on success or something like that, just the push function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278006/how-can-i-dynamically-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-yui-datatable

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with defining the DataTable providing an empty array for its initial data.  Then, for each new piece of information you just call addRow.  There is no need to deal with any DataSource.

See the code block at:  http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/#using

Instead of having data loaded with all those values simply make: `var data = [];`

Later on, use addRow for the new rows.