# How can I dynamically add rows and columns to a YUI dataTable

Tags: yui, yui3

I am trying to modify the [the YUI sortable `dataTable` example](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-sort.html) to add rows and columns dynamically after the `dataTable` is created. My code looks like this:

```js
YUI().use("datatable-sort", function(Y) {
    var cols = [
        {key:"Company", label:"Click to Sort Column A", sortable:true},
        {key:"Phone", label:"Not Sortable Column B"},
        {key:"Contact", label:"Click to Sort Column C", sortable:true}
    ],
    data = [
        {Company:"Company Bee", Phone:"415-555-1234", Contact:"Sally Spencer"},
        {Company:"Acme Company", Phone:"650-555-4444", Contact:"John Jones"},
        {Company:"Industrial Industries", Phone:"408-555-5678", Contact:"Robin Smith"}
    ],
    table = new Y.DataTable({
        columns: cols,
        data   : data,
        summary: "Contacts list",
        caption: "Table with simple column sorting"
    }).render("#sort");

    // Add rows and columns here.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically add rows into a YUI `dataTable` by calling the [`addRow()`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#method_addRow) or [`addRows()`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#method_addRows) method. If you are using the [YUI sortable dataTable example](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-sort.html), you could do it this way:

```
table.addRows(
    [{Company:"New Company", Phone:"555-555-5555", Contact:"John Smith"},
    {Company:"Old Company", Phone:"555-555-6666", Contact:"Rowdy Piper"}]);
```

Dynamically loading `columns` can be done similarly with [`addColumn()`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#method_addColumn):

```
 table.addColumn({key:"NewColumn", label:"Column D"});
```

**Note:** you must include the `datatable-mutable` module in your code to utilize these methods.